# JPA properly update an Entity - EntityUpdate results in IntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I tried to update my Entity with the following code:

An uncommented version (may be more readable):

```
MyEntity entity = MyConverter.dtoToEntity(fooDto);  
MyEntity existingEntity = this.repo.getEntityByNumber(entity.getNumber()).orElse(null); 
existingEntity = entity; 
this.entityManager.merge(existingEntity);
```

Here's a commented version (to see what I thought while writing it).

```
//this dto came from a RestController   
MyEntity entity = MyConverter.dtoToEntity(fooDto);  

//null would mean it is not existing
//getEntityByNumber selects an Entity by a given Number - the Number is a unique number but not the PK
MyEntity existingEntity = this.repo.getEntityByNumber(entity.getNumber()).orElse(null); 

 //update the found entity to the existing entity
existingEntity = entity;

//merge it to override the changes if existing or create a new one.
this.entityManager.merge(existingEntity);
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-12-30 00:32:47.944 ERROR 18708 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Test' for key 'UC_NUMBER'
```

So it seems like he'd try to create a new entry, but there is an existing one, why'd he do that?

**Edit:**
So to clarify what I try to do:

I get an DTO (`fooDto`) from a REST-API that has changes in it but should already exist in my database and now I'd like to save these changes in that database-entry.

So what I tried using the `entityManager` to save the received dto directly into my database which resulted in the same error I am getting now. Then I starting trying around with `this.repo.save()` instead and then I thought I might just need to grab the existing entry and overwrite it. Sadly nothing of these seems to work out for me.

**Edit 2:**

The column where the unique constraint fails is NOT the Primary Key-column. My Column-Definition for that is:

```
@Column(name = "NUMBER", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String number;
```

**Edit 3:**

My `getIdentityByNumber` is defined in my repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from TABLE p where p.NUMBER = :num", nativeQuery=true)
public Optional<MyEntity> getIdentityByNumber(@Param("num") String num);
```

Comment: Why ignore 'his' own test? `existingEntity = entity;` just overwrites the previous fetch, assuming that works.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Let me try to explain what I thought it'd do. I used to call `this.entityManager.merge(entity)` which would cause in the same error I am getting now. So I thought I might needed to get the existing Entity to insert my changes coming in from the REST-API, so I selected the `existingEntity` and tried to simply "overwrite" its attributes by using `existingEntity = entity;` and then merge this back in. Using `this.repo.save(entity)` or `this.repo.save(existingEntity)` instead of `this.entityManager.merge(...)` did not change the outcome btw.

Comment: Well, there is a lot on that here and you're correct in your assumption, but you may also consider whether JPA and the database are out of sync. That's the more typical case when you get SQL constraint violation when trying to insert. Did you insert the original entity with a native insert or perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the entry got created via JPA. Can I somehow ensure that they are in sync again?

Comment: Well if you created it with `createNativeQuery` then doing the findBy should sync the database. If you are getting SQL exception then the `findBy` didn't find it. You still can't just replace what was found, you have to update the fields you want to update after that.

Comment: Does the entity created by transforming the DTO have a non-null ID? If not, then you're asking Hibernate to create a new one, because Hibernate identifies entities by their ID, not by their number. Your call to getEntityByNumber is completely unnecessary, since you're not doig anything with what it returns anyway.